# Membership sign-up fatal error: Duplicate entry, already exists

Tags: civimember

A user has tried to sign-up for a new membership. They have tried and failed multiple times. The log shows:

> $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => -5 [message] => DB Error: already exists [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_line_item (entity_table , entity_id , contribution_id , price_field_id , label , qty , unit_price , line_total , participant_count , price_field_value_id , financial_type_id ) VALUES ('civicrm_membership' , ***** , ***** , 6 , '*****' , 1 , *** , *** , 0 , 7 , 2 ) [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'civicrm_membership-*****-*****-7-6' for key 'UI_line_item_value'] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_line_item (entity_table , entity_id , contribution_id , price_field_id , label , qty , unit_price , line_total , participant_count , price_field_value_id , financial_type_id ) VALUES ('civicrm_membership' , ***** , ***** , 6 , '*****' , 1 , *** , *** , 0 , 7 , 2 ) [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'civicrm_membership-*****-*****-7-6' for key 'UI_line_item_value'] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: already exists" code=-5 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_line_item (entity_table , entity_id , contribution_id , price_field_id , label , qty , unit_price , line_total , participant_count , price_field_value_id , financial_type_id ) VALUES ('civicrm_membership' , ***** , ***** , 6 , '*****' , 1 , *** , *** , 0 , 7 , 2 ) [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'civicrm_membership-*****-*****-7-6' for key 'UI_line_item_value']"] )

I have seen a similar bug report but that was for membership renewals and was fixed for 4.5. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14894

We are running 4.6.7 on Drupal 7.39

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the same error for all the membership or just for single user

This error occurs when the confirmation button is clicked twice

did you check the DB - it should have already created membership record and also related contribution and line_item record

so please try to cancel the users existing membership and ask him to try again